# The location of an application shown in Dash menu

Tags: 14.04, unity-dash, location

In "dash" menu there're a few applications, or rather links to the applications, which don't exist in `/usr/share/applications` and which I want to copy to my desktop. 
I've tried to "locate" and "find" but met with no success.
I'm unable to drag them to Desktop because of the well-known error.

Where can I find them?

Comment: (if you can start these applications, and they have a window)

Comment: Which are the applications? Some (mostly downloaded & locally installed-)applications install .desktop files locally in `~/.local/share/applications` . In that case: copy the `.desktop` files from `~/.local/share/applications` on to your desktop and make them exectuable.

Comment: @JacobVlijm, it's meteparat.

Comment: @AlanCoromano Never heard of that, how did you install?

Comment: @JacobVlijm, so why did you ask? do you know of all the applications for ubuntu?

Comment: @AlanCoromano Huh? trying to help here, but ok, have a nice day.